# Joining three numeric columns without adding them in r

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a df with three columns (among others) with "date-data": day, month and year. I am wondering if there is any clever way to join them to one column with "DD-MM_YYYY" instead? Perhaps with lubridate?

```
`day<-c(2, 4, 22, 7, 17, 12)
month<-c(2, 1, 6, 12, 10, 5)
year<-c(1999, 2000, 2001, 1977, 1982, 1940)
df<-data.frame(day, month, year)`
```

I have only joined string columns before or created column where I have done computations. This is new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned `lubridate`, how about this?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
    unite(dmy, day, month, year) %>%
    transmute(dmy = dmy(dmy))
#         dmy
#1 1999-02-02
#2 2000-01-04
#3 2001-06-22
#4 1977-12-07
#5 1982-10-17
#6 1940-05-12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df$date <- as.Date(with(df, paste(day, month, year,sep="-")), "%d-%m-%y")
```